# How to calculate time for Sitecore media library activities?

Tags: media-library

Client is complaining regarding slowness of the Sitecore `media library`, activities like opening media folder, uploading image, saving image, using media in `Experience editor`.

Before making any changes, we would like to measure current performance. Is there any tool online or `marketplace` which can help us to measure time of the activities performed in `media library`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such a tool which would specifically measure performance of activities in media library.

You can use tools like `JetBrains dotTrace profiler` to measure performance of any .net application.

From my experience, if you have issues with performance of media library dialogs, most probably it's related to Sitecore facets (image from Sitecore documentation - link below):

[image]

> Select Media dialog facets are defined in the core database under the `/sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/SelectMediaDialog/PageSettings/Facets` folder and can be disabled by deleting the correspondent items.

Read more in the article **[Using faceting feature might lead to high memory usage or site outage](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/576214)**

And if uploading of new media items takes long, there is high probability it's related to media indexing. You may think about using `intervalAsyncMaster` indexing strategy for `sitecore_master_index`. Good idea may be to set `CheckForThreshold` value to `false`. Otherwise full index rebuild will be scheduled if many items were changed in `master` database:

```
<intervalAsyncMaster type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.IntervalAsynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
  <param desc="database">master</param>
  <param desc="interval">00:00:05</param>
  <CheckForThreshold>false</CheckForThreshold>
</intervalAsyncMaster>
```

Comment: Thanks Marek for your response. I will check the points which you have mentioned and will update if it helps.